# Scrollview listview in jQuery Mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, scroll

Is there any way to accomplish the following component:

Div that serves as a "mask" of smaller size for a list of filter and scroll as the daughter of a larger size.

I got put on the list using the scroll iscroll and iscrollview. But do not mention that in the corresponding size. Explaining better 150px div should contain and the list contains a much greater height. And problems occur when there is focus on the filter list because the list should scroll without these attributes to not be on the list with scroll and filter:
date-tap-toggle = "false" data-position = "fixed". Following codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"
    charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="style/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"
            data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul class="ui-grid-b">
                    <li class="ui-block-a"><a href="#"
                        data-href="center" id="btnCenter"
                        data-transition="none" data-theme="b">Center</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-block-b"><a href="#"
                        class="ui-btn-active" data-href="rast"
                        id="btnRast" data-transition="none" data-theme="b">Rast</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-block-c"><a href="#" data-href="help"
                        id="btnHelp" data-transition="none" data-theme="b">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">


            <div id="listFilter" height: 150px
                style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10%; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 5%;">

                        <ul id="listVeiculos" data-role="listview" data-theme="d"
                            data-filter-placeholder="Ve&iacute;culos" data-filter="true"
                            data-divider-theme="d" data-scroll="y">
                            <li data-role="list-divider">
                                <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                    <div class="ui-block-a">A</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-b">B</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-c">C</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-d">D</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                    <div class="ui-block-a">001</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-b">002</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-c">003</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-d">004</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div class="ui-grid-c">

                                    <div class="ui-block-a">001</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-b">002</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-c">003</div>

                                    <div class="ui-block-d">004</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="content_div" style="margin-top: 5%;" id="divListWithouScroll"   
            data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">

            <div>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="listWithouScroll"
                    style="margin-top: 5%; border: 0px" data-theme="d"
                    data-dividertheme="d">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">1</li>
                    <li data-role="text">2</li>
                    <li data-role="text">3</li>
                    <li data-role="text">4</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/iscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the following line of code but it deprives all screens can use the feature, and only this screen should not: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing".

Thanks!